# How do you remove the port number :8000 from project-open url links?

Tags: tcl, project-open

We have nginx acting as a reverse proxy for project-open which is working. https://sourceforge.net/projects/project-open/reviews/
nginx is set to pass requests on port 443 (https) to 127.0.0.1:8000 which is the port naviserver is running on which is serving project-open.

Everytime we click on a link in project-open the url includes the port number the naviserver is running on which bypasses the nginx proxy. Removing the :8000 manually from the url works.

I changed the proxy setting to true in /web/projop/etc/config.tcl

```
# set proxy_mode          false
set proxy_mode true
```

which didn't seem to make any difference.

How do you remove the port number :8000 from project-open url links?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to
ADMIN->PARAMETERS and change Parameter

```
    SuppressHttpPort
```

of package:

```
    acs-tcl
```

acccordingly.